# Pass multiple elements to an each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

```
function generalShowPopup(click_element, show_elements) {
  click_element.on("click", function(event) {
    show_elements.each(function() {
      $(this).show();
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

With the above function I intend to show an element when a certain link is clicked.

Calling the function like this (one second argument) works fine:

```
generalShowPopup($(".popup_link"), $(".popup") );
```

But how could I pass two elements to the second argument, i.e show two elements when a certain link is clicked?

Comment: You mean two elements at a time or just two elements? I mean, it's a .each, so it can reveal two elements if the .popup selector matchs two elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a comma, `,`, inside the selector string, and there really is no reason to use `.each()`:

```
generalShowPopup($(".popup_link"), $(".popup,.selecctor2, #selector3") );
```

No need to use each:

```
function generalShowPopup(click_element, show_elements) {
    click_element.on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        show_elements.show();
    });
}
```

**A quicker way to write all this is**:

```
$(function() {
    $(".popup_link").on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".popup,.selecctor2, #selector3").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(".popup")` is a jQuery Collection,

Just use `.add()` method:

```
generalShowPopup($(".popup_link"), $(".popup").add(".another") );
```